# Generating a .jpg image with sencha touch 2 and the draw object

Tags: bitmap, sencha-touch-2, draw

I don't have much experience with Sencha Touch or it's drawing and charting package, but I am faced with a project that I need to be sure I can complete with this development framework.

The application must be able to combine a predefined bitmap image (in whatever format it is deemed more convenient) with text typed in by the user. The application must take the typed in text, scale it and rotate it to fit in a pre-set area in the image and then generate a new bitmap image that contains the text.

Is this possible with sencha touch 2?

Any pointers to usefull information?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Sencha touch 2 it is possible. But there is no built-in package available for sencha But Sencha Touch welcomes you to code and customize Ext.draw object using its components. 
  First you need a Canvas which extends component in which drawing should be done. 
  Getting canvas object and getting canvas object events like dragend,dragstart,move,etc. Using event object we could determine the current position in the canvas ie,

> `e.pageX and e.pageY`

In canvas object

{ //getting image from canvas

> canvasObject.getContext("2d").getImageData(0,0,this.width,this.height)
>   Key Logic on saving the Image is Encoding to Particular format Here is
>   JPEG Encoder is ther encode function
>
> ```
> this.encode = function(image,quality) // image data object     {
>
>           if(quality) setQuality(quality);
>           // Initialize bit writer
>           byteout = new Array();
>           // Add JPEG headers
>                             //converting image bit to jpegbase64 encoding
>                             // Encode 8x8 macroblocks
> ```
>
> //byteout is output formed by conversion of image
>                           var jpegDataUri = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + byteout.join(''); 
>   bytes  to jpeg bytes }

Looking in the example ux.signatureField will give you clear understanding.

Check this example of signature field demo [link](http://morointeractive.com/sencha-touch-2-signature-field-with-android-todataurl-work-around/)